# How to emulate 'const auto' with BOOST_AUTO in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Using the `BOOST_AUTO` macro we can emulate the `auto` keyword that isn't available before C++11:

```
BOOST_AUTO( var, 1 + 2 ); // int var = 3
auto var = 1 + 2; // the same in C++11
```

Is there any way to emulate `const auto`?

```
const auto var = 1 + 2; // const int var = 3
```

Comment: Can't you just stick `const` in front of the macro? It works for me in VC++, but YMMV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just include the "trailing" const:

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>

int main()
{
    BOOST_AUTO(const x, 42);

    static_assert(std::is_const<decltype(x)>(), "weehoo");
}
```

The trailing position is the only consistent position for the `const` qualifier for many reasons. This is one of them :)