# Retrieving the type of auto in C++11 without executing the program

Tags: c++, c++11, static-analysis

I have some C++11 code using the `auto` inferred type that I have to convert to C++98. How would I go about converting the code, substituting in the actual type for all instances of `auto`?

Comment: `auto` is compile time, not runtime. It's a convenience feature, so you could just deduce the type from the expression. If that's difficult, just replace `auto` with a type you know is wrong and look at the compiler's error message. "cannot convert from 'x' to 'y'" where 'x' is your type.

Comment: Why are you converting it back if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: That's one way to do it manually, but I'd like to automate the process, and I don't know how to deduce the type. I want to do this because I have to submit source code for solutions to a programming contest, and their system only compiles C++98.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266391/find-out-the-type-of-auto

Comment: @BryanChen: that is similar but their solutions require running the program.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is going to be a PITA, but you can declare an incomplete struct template accepting a single type parameter.

Given the variable `x` you want to know the type of, you can use the struct with `decltype(x)` and that will lead to a compiler error that will show you the inferred type.

For example:

```
template<class Type> struct S;

int main() {
    auto x = ...;
    S<decltype(x)>();
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf76ee97361a350e)

which will produce an error message in the form:

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'S<X>' (clang++)
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct S<X>' (g++)
```

with `X` being the inferred type. In this particular case the type is `int`.

**Trivia:** This has been recommended by Scott Meyer in one of the recent NDC 2014's videos (I don't remember which one).

Comment: This approach gets pretty hairy when containers from the standard library are used. Check out http://ideone.com/A44Y9C.

Comment: This only works if the compiler implements `decltype`, which is likewise a C++11 extension. Pre-C++11 compilers do implement this feature variously as `typeof` (GCC, Clang) or `decltype` (MSVC) but not with exactly the same semantics as were standardized.

Answer (score 5):

As `auto` is known at compile-time, you need to interoperate with the compiler.

One option would be the [Clang compiler](http://clang.llvm.org/)'s [LibTooling library](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) that provides infrastructure that you can base static analysis tools on.
For example, look at their [refactoring example code](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk/remove-cstr-calls/) that removes superfluous `.c_str()` calls from the code. I think you could write a similar tool that converts `auto` into the inferred type.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `BOOST_AUTO` macro in the [Boost typeof library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.auto).

```
auto x = 5 + 7;
```

becomes

```
BOOST_AUTO(x,5+7);
```

Comment: Interesting, so if I just run the preprocessor it'll directly replace the expression with a literal type? Or does it come with some strings attached, like decltype?

Comment: @user1825464 As far as I know it should work. Though you might want to note how to declare `const auto x`. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458505/how-to-emulate-const-auto-with-boost-auto-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You could use typeid and std::type_info::name();

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <complex>

int
main()
{
  using namespace std::literals::complex_literals;

  auto x = 3.1415F;
  std::cout << typeid(x).name() << '\n';
  auto z = 1.0 + 1.0i;
  std::cout << typeid(z).name() << '\n';
}

$ /home/ed/bin_concepts/bin/g++ -std=c++14 typeid.cpp 

$ ./a.out
f
St7complexIdE
```

The names aren't beautiful but you can at least translate them.
These names are got from g++.  The name is compiler dependent.
There is some movement to standardize a pretty_name().
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname) is a non-standard way to unmangle the names.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use function templates and type deduction.  It may not work in all examples you have but it may help in some cases:

```
int foo ()
{
   auto x = bar();
   // do something with 'x'
}
```

Change this to:

```
template <typename T> int foo_(T x)
{
   // do something with 'x'
}

int foo ()
{
   foo_(bar());
}
```

`auto` is specified in terms of type deduction, so the above should have very similar, if not identical semantics as the C++ '11 version.