# Is there a feature of the compiler for substituting auto with the inferred type in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, clang++

`auto` is comfortable to use but sometimes, for a matter of legibility while programming I would prefer to have the inferred type written in the source code instead of auto.

Is there a functionality of gcc/clang or some other tool/VSCode extension ( for linux or macos ) that takes as input the source files and spits back the same source files but with `auto` replaced by its inferred type?

I tried googling but and the closest thing I've found is this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441505/retrieving-the-type-of-auto-in-c11-without-executing-the-program) and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: A good IDE should show you what the type is if you hover with the mouse on it.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis VSCode does it, sometimes, but in situations like in #ifdef blocks it doesn't work if the if condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Compilers are usually not modifying the source code, this is the job of the editor, IDE or other editing tools. It seems for example ReSharper C++ (a Visual Studio extension) can do this: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/features/ > For example, you can quickly replace auto with explicit type or replace type with auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not always possible. In the following case, the compiler cannot substitute `auto` with **one** type, because 3 different functions get actually instantiated.

```
template<typename T>
auto f(T x) {
    auto y = x;
    return y;
}

int main() {
    f(1);
    f('c');
    f("c");
}
```

Someone in the comments says that it should substitute `auto` for `T`, because that's actually what happens in my trivial example: `auto` is deduced to be the same type **as `T` is deduced to be**, which in my opinion just means that in this example `auto` is playing the same role as `T`, which is the "placeholder" (maybe this is not the right terminology) for the type the compiler will deduce at each call site. Even if you substitute `auto` for `T` (in this trivial example), what invermation are you getting more than you had? Nothing.

If the `main` above was instead

```
int main() {
    f(1);
}
```

then yes, you or the compiler could substitute `auto` with `int` (or whatever), but in the original code, there would be no **single** substitution that would make happy all three lines inside that `main`. The compile could just substitute the whole template function with a sequence of the various instantiations that it needs. And the number of those depends on how many different types are passed to `f` in the whole codebase that makes use of `f`.

If **you** write a library, with a nice template function in it, you cannot know which types it will be instatiated with, when **I** will use it in **my** code; so what are you substituting `T` or `auto` with?

Comment: Some types (like lambdas) are unique and indescribable.

Comment: What should the compiler deduce for the `auto` in this code, in your opinion? Not to mention what @Suma just wrote.

Comment: It's always possible, but often you would see the uglified internal type names, not the exposed interfaces. Resolving the canonical name for types is the actually tricky part.

Comment: Yes it is, what are you talking about? Template functions are no different, their code gets copied and adjusted for each type usage you have. At every single point you have hard, static types for every variable.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Lambdas are better example, but I see your point - such a tool would be lacking as in "it sometimes works and sometimes not"

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis In my opinion the tool I'm looking for could leave auto at the function definition and replace auto in situations like `auto c = f('c')`

Comment: Maybe this would be a better example: https://godbolt.org/z/W839zj

Comment: @Suma, is there any more information in saying that _the type of `y` is whatever `T` is deduced to be_ with respect to _the type of `y` is whatever `auto` is deduced to be_? They're just the same, they also use the same type deduction rules (except when braced initializers are concerned).

Answer (score 2):

In combination with using `clang` as a compiler, you use [`clangd`](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd) for auto-completion, … and it will show the type of `auto` on mouseover (as long as it does not depend on a template variable)

Comment: The MS extension shows you auto types on hover as well.

Comment: @sweenish oh ok, the last time I used it it didn't work.

Comment: clangd is probably what's used by the vscode extension since it works exaclty as you said, but as I said in the comment of the question, for things like #ifdef blocks or `auto [a,b,c] = f()` it does not work.

Comment: @GerardoZinno, it is. VSCode uses clangd.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis do you know if there's the possibility to make it substitute `auto` when it can?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, but the whole point is what I'm gonna explain better in my answer in a minute.

Comment: @t.niese can you use clangd from the terminal to make it substitute auto? Or can I use it only from IDEs and with the mouseover?