# why does shifting a uint16_t get an int

Tags: c++

I was writing some code in C++ with templates, and there was a parameter like `uint16_t >> uint16_t`, but the compiler deduced `T = int`.

There is also an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mfcnn6M5T):

```
#include <cstdint>
template<class Type> struct S;
void foo() {
    S<decltype(uint16_t(1) >> uint16_t(1))>();
}
```

Where the compiler (x86-64 gcc 10.3) gave

```
<source>: In function 'void foo()':
<source>:4:45: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct S<int>'
    4 |     S<decltype(uint16_t(1) >> uint16_t(1))>();
      |
```

But why is `uint16_t(1) >> uint16_t(1)` an `int`?

(I learnt this method of getting the type in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24455231/14430730))

Comment: Because shifting is an arthmetic operation and promotion to `int` happens.

Comment: I'm clear now! [Integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) says: arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. Thanks for marking the duplicate!

Comment: And just to add to the confusion, if the compiler uses 16-bit `int`s there will be no conversion.